# how to get reference to model from post save handler in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to run an aggregate query and save the result to a search engine after a mongoose model is saved.

The problem is, I can't figure out how to get a reference to the `aggregate` function from within the method. I tried below, but `schema.aggregate` is not defined. I also tried directly `model.aggregate` but it's not defined.

How can I get a reference to some object able to run the aggregate query?

```
/**
 * Update search index
 */
InventorySchema.post('save', function(model, done){
  var query = new ItemUpdateQuery(model.partNumber, model.schema);
  query.exec(function(err, result){
    if (err) return done(err);
    searchUtils.saveDocument('Inventory', result, done);
  });
});

/**
 * The query updates the inventory index for a specific item. It transforms the corresponding inventory record so it can
 * be imported or reimported into the search index.
 *
 * This was moved into the file to avoid a circular reference issue.
 *
 * @param partNumber The part number to update.
 * @param Schema Reference to the schema to
 */
function ItemUpdateQuery (partNumber, Schema){

  return Schema.aggregate(
    {"$unwind": "$records"},
    {
      "$lookup": {
        "from": 'locations',
        "localField": "records.location",
        'foreignField': '_id',
        as: 'location'
      }
    },
    {"$lookup": {"from": "items", "localField": "item", 'foreignField': '_id', as: 'item'}},
    {"$match": {"$records.enabled": true, "item.partNumber": partNumber}},
    {
      "$project": {
        "_id": "$records._id",
        "onHand": "$records.onHand",
        "shipped": "$records.shipped",
        "allocated": "$records.allocated",
        "backOrderAvailable": "$records.backOrderAvailable",
        "backOrdered": "$records.backOrdered",
        "backOrderEstimatedShipDate": "$records.backOrderEstimatedShipDate",
        "enabled": "$records.enabled",
        "perpetual": "$records.perpetual",
        "location": "$location",
        "item": "$item",
        "geo": "$records.location.address.geo.location"
      }
    }
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this correctly, you are a bit off with the definitions of Schema, Method and Document.

> Models are fancy constructors compiled from our Schema definitions. Instances of these models represent documents which can be saved and retrieved from our database. All document creation and retrieval from the database is handled by these models.

Starting from your ItemUpdateQuery function:
`return Schema.aggregate()`

.aggregate() is not a method of Schema, but a method of Model. If I get this correctly, what you're referencing as Schema in this function, should actually be a Model.

Then here:
`InventorySchema.post('save', function(model, done) {})`

The callback here is not `function(model, done)`, but `function(document, done)`. document is an instance of Model, therefore you can access your Model as document.constructor, and your aggregate() method as document.constructor.aggregate();

Or to put it short:

```
InventorySchema.post('save', function(document, done) {
  //document.constructor references the Model
}
```

Comment: thanks, yep that's what I needed to know, `.constructor` should probably be called `.model` no wonder I couldn't find it.

Comment: .model() is a method on the main mongoose object, which sets a model if called with two arguments but also works as a getter if only called with one argument. So I think this.model('modelName') could also work.
Also, please consider accepting the answer if a better one doesn't come along :)